# Returning Yes or No depending on results of 2 date columns

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi

I am trying to calculate if someone was employed in the last 12 months based on 2 date fields. Joined date & Date left. If they were an employee in the last 12 months and have not left return 'Yes' if they either joined in the last 12 months or left in the last 12 months return 'No'.I also want it to only show full time employees based on a column that contains ('Contract' / 'FT').

The image linked table shows the inputs. I want a formula to calculate the 'Employeed in last 12 months'.

Thank you.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPBZg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new column in your table, with expression like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Employeed in Last 12 Months",
    each if [#"Contract/FT"] <> "FT" then "No"
    else if [Date Left] <> null then "No"
    else if [Date Joined] > Date.AddYears(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()), -1) then "No"
    else "Yes")
```

[image]

[`DateTime.LocalNow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-localnow) returns current date and time. This value is recalculated when you reload the data (note, it will not be recalculated automatically in time - you must reload the data).

[`Date.From`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-from) will truncate the time part.

[`Date.AddYears`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-addyears) will add -1 years, i.e. will calculate the date 1 year ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF('Table'[Contract/ FT]="FT";
IF(DATEDIFF('Table'[Date Joined].[Date];TODAY();MONTH)>12;
IF(ISBLANK('Table'[Date Left]);
"YES";
"NO");
"NO");
"NO")
```

Add new column and add above expression, it will give you desired results